# how to see memory usage of my application through the JMX using programatically

Tags: java, jmx

I have four applications. And i want develop Simple Application that will give me

Memory Usage, CPU Usage like things individually. like in List box i have putted my

four Applications and when user selects one then it will show its options like

ShowMemoryUsageOfThisSelectedApplication(Method has to use JMX)

ShowCPUUsageOfThisSelectedApplication(Method has to use JMX).

How to do this ?

I have Simple knowledge to Run simple Application and See in jconsole.

I did Example of following URL.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html

My four Applications are running in Single Tomcat.

Any Suggestions will be Appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do via JMX. You can dump memory heap and analyze it, to investigate what classloader how much memory consumed, Eclipce can help here, i suppose.

Things would be a lot more simple if every application will work on his own tomcat instance.

Comment: IF four application running on four different instances then memory Allocation in jvm will be different or Same for Every Application?

Comment: You can dump memory heap and analyze it, to investigate what classloader how much memory consumed, How to do this ?

Comment: In case four differrent Tomcat instances memory consumption should be a bit more, depends of how much shared classes your application uses.

Comment: about memory dump analizing http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Fgettingstarted%2Fbasictutorial.html